# how to stop an if else condition in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How to pause, stop, or abort an If Else expression when the result excepted has been achieved ?

I want check if somes folders exists, exemple 1, 2, and 3. But I want stop and create only one missing folder. If folder 1 and 3 exists, create the 2 only.

For this exemple I tell about 3 folders for explain quick, really I need more directories.

There is my code, i don't know why this don't work ... It create folders but, crash my program

```vb
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim dirNumber As Integer = 1
    Dim stopFunction As String
    stopFunction = "null"
    Dim DIR_PATH_test As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\testdir\" & dirNumber)

    If DIR_PATH_test.Exists Then
        '1 exists
        dirNumber = dirNumber + 1 '2

    ElseIf DIR_PATH_test.Exists Then
        '2 exists
        dirNumber = dirNumber + 1 '3

    ElseIf DIR_PATH_test.Exists Then
        '3 exists
        ' dirNumber already 3 do nothing
        dirNumber = dirNumber + 1
    Else
        stopFunction = "stop"

    End If
    If stopFunction = "null" Then
        Dim DIR_NAME_test As String = "C:\testdir\" & dirNumber
        MsgBox("dir name = " & DIR_NAME_test)
        MsgBox("dir number = " & dirNumber)
        MkDir(DIR_NAME_test)
    End If
End Sub
```

If anyone can tell me why it don't appropriate. Ty

EDIT :

This don't work too.

```vb
Dim dirNumber As Integer = 1
Dim DIR_PATH_test As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\testdir\" & dirNumber)
Dim DIR_NAME_test As String = "C:\testdir\" & dirNumber
If DIR_PATH_test.Exists Then
    '1 exists
    dirNumber = dirNumber + 1
    ' 2 
    If DIR_PATH_test.Exists Then
        '2 exists
        dirNumber = dirNumber + 1
        ' 3
        If DIR_PATH_test.Exists Then
            '3 exists
            ' dirNumber = 3 don't increment
        Else
            MkDir(DIR_NAME_test)
        End If
    Else
        MkDir(DIR_NAME_test)
    End If
Else
    MkDir(DIR_NAME_test)
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are repeating the same thing over and over, use a loop. Don't forget to create a new `DirectoryInfo` at each loop iteration to reflect the new directory name (in your code you are creating it only once and thus are testing for dirnumber = 1 over and over).

```vb
Dim baseDir As String = "C:\testdir\"

For dirNumber As Integer = 1 To 3
    Dim dirInfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(baseDir, dirNumber.ToString())
    If Not dirInfo.Exists Then
        dirInfo.Create()
        Exit For ' Create only one directory
    End If
Next
```

Note, this assumes that the directory name is "1", "2" or "3".

If you want to create **all** missing directories, just drop the `Exit For`.

Comment: Wow more clear and less lines. Ty